# Typescript compile error on enum equality check

Tags: typescript, enums, equality

I created this typescript file to show the problem:

```
enum E {
    one,
    two
}

console.log(E.one)
console.log(E.two)

let n: E = E.one
if (n === E.one) console.log("equal");
if (n === E.two) console.log("equal");
```

I get compile error from tsc on second if:

```
test.ts:11:5 - error TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'E.one' and 'E.two' have no overlap.
```

I can't find out why it is happening. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intended behaviour (see this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42654)).

TypeScript's control flow analysis is smart enough to see that you just assigned `E.one` to `n`. There is now *"invisible"* type information associated with `n` which *narrows* down its type to `E.one` and will lead to the error in the if-statement because it knows that the condition will *always* evaluate to `false`.

If you want to avoid this behaviour, you can use the `as` operator which lets TypeScript conveniently *forget* the narrowed type information about `n`.

```
let n: E = E.one as E

if (n === E.one) console.log("equal");
if (n === E.two) console.log("equal");
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=14#code/KYOwrgtgBAolDeBYAUFNUD2JgBoXqgBcB3DFAXxRQGMsBnDAG2ADpGMBzAChha2ACUNek1btuvEhiHIUzQlBAAuWFAC8sPtigBDOrBQBLAGZQuIdWo29%20AqLRANmbTlwBEwAI5gdjNwIBuI1NzS2sWKTsHJzFXD29ffwCgA)

Comment: It is a strange behavior and I commented on it in the pointed issue.